# Proof for nonexistent of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$$

Is non existent.

This is my attempt:

Assume The limit $= L$ Some real number $L$

By the definition of one sided limits we get from right and left respectively:

For $\delta > 0, \epsilon > 0$
$$x< \delta \implies \left| 1/x - L \right| < \epsilon$$

$$-x < \delta_2 \implies \left| 1/x - L \right| < \epsilon$$

Let $\delta' = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$

Let $\epsilon = 1$

$$x< \delta \implies \left| 1/x - L \right| < 1$$

$$-x < \delta_2 \implies \left| 1/x - L \right| < 1$$

---

$$0 < \delta_1 + \delta_2 \implies 2|1/x - L| < 2$$

what else should I do?

Comment: Your definition of the one-sided limit is wrong. "There exists" and "for all" are different. They should not be confused, and the order cannot be changed. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. For left/right limit, you just have $x$ further restricted to the left/right of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first answer in Stackexchange. I hope that my answer can give you some help. 
It's said that the limit of $f(x)$ is L when x approaches to $0$ if the following statement is true:

For every $\delta>0$, there exists $x_0>0$ such that for $\left|x\right|<x_0$ implies that $\left| f(x)-L \right|<\delta$.

Here we assume this statement holds for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. There exists L, that for every $\delta>0$, there exists $x_0$ such that for $\left|x\right|<x_0$ implies that $\left| \frac{1}{x}-L \right|<\delta$.

Given $\delta$ and $L$, apply them to the inequality:$$\left| \frac{1}{x}-L \right|<\delta$$

$$\frac{1}{x}-L<\delta$$
$$x>\frac{1}{L+\delta}$$

Just consider the case when $L>-\delta$. Here needs some attention, because if we want to get a paradox for a statement with every or any, we just give an example where the statement is not true, then the whole statement is not true.

So that if $0<x<\min(x_0,\frac{1}{L+\delta})$,  $\left| \frac{1}{x}-L \right|>\delta$ which is contrast to the original statement because we find a $x$, whose absolute value is smaller than $x_0$ while not satisfied with the inequality.

Proof is finished.

Comment: How can you consider a specific $L$ case?

Comment: @Amad27 I don't specify L, I just specify $\delta$, because my goal is to prove some(not any) $\delta$ that is not satisfied with that statement under the assumption of L's existence. So a specific $\delta$ is considered and then we can conclude that L does not exists. Here involves a series of logical reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, this proof needs a lot more explanation. A mathematical proof is not just a series of symbols: it is a flow of ideas, and ideas are best conveyed using both symbols and **SENTENCES**.

For example, you say you assume that the limit is $L$. OK, now I understand what $L$ is, but what are $\delta, \delta_2$ and $x$? And what is $\epsilon$? Explain these things in sentences and make it clear what you are trying to prove, what follows from what, and, most importantly, why this means that the limit does not exist.

---

A **hint**:

The statement

> $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exitsts

is equivalent to saying:

> There exists such a $L$ that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists such a $\delta > 0$ that from $|x-x_0|<\delta$, it follows that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, you must prove that the limit does not exist, meaning that this statement is not true. What is the negation of this statement?

As I see you are a beginner, I will help a little more:

To prove that $f$ has no limit, you must prove that for every $L$, $L$ is not a limit, meaning that there, for every $\delta > 0$, there exists such an $x$ that $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - L| > \epsilon$.

Comment: I didnt prove it, I need help proving it.

Comment: @Amad27 I didn't know that. You know *why* I didn't know that? Because I have no idea what you were trying to do. Please, explain what you were trying to do using both sentences and symbols. All my comments still stand.

Comment: Sorry, Ill update the question.

Comment: @Amad27 Still not good. Did you *pick* an $\epsilon$? Are you saying that you take an arbitrary $\epsilon$?

Comment: Am I supposed to pick an $\epsilon$

Comment: @Amad27 See the question that I posted at the end of my hint. Can you answer it?

Comment: I took an "arbitrary" $\epsilon$ I dont know which special case to pick

Comment: @Amad27 See the question that I posted at the end of my hint. Can you answer it?

Comment: I wish I was as good in English as you. Negation is a tough term, would you mind simplifying it?

Comment: @Amad27 The opposite. For example, If I want to prove that the statement $\forall x: f(x)>0$, I must prove the statement $\exists x: f(x) \leq 0$. This statement is the *negation* of the original.

Comment: The symbols are alien to me. I am a beginner in proofs, sorry for inconveniece, I dont understand the symbols, but Ill try. In the problem you must prove that $|f(x) - L| > \epsilon$ then, if the negation is false. Isnt it?

Comment: @Amad27 I have no idea what you tried to say in your last sentence.

Comment: So I want to prove that the statement is false. the way to do that is the opposite. The statement says: $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, so to prove that false would be to prove that $|f(x) - L| > \epsilon$?

Comment: @Amad27 No. You have to negate the *whole* statement, I.E. the statement "There exists such a $L$ that for *every* $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|1/x - L|<\epsilon$ for every $x$, $|x|<\delta$."

Comment: Sorry for this, I truly do not understand, I feel this is an issue of semantics, and my  English is hindering my understanding. What should I prove?

Comment: @Amad27 I don't really think that this is an appropriate site for this condition. What you lack is not the explanation to your question, but a much more thorough understanding of limits. I advise you to take a lot of time to re-read your lecture notes and re-do the exercises you did so far. I *can* tell you the answer you need, but it will be useless to you.

Comment: Perhaps I can learn from that?

Comment: @Amad27 From my answer? No. You can learn much much more by re-reading the stuff you don't understand for now, and then try to solve the problem you are solving now. It isn't hard, you will succeed, and learn a lot from it. Trust me. I did enough tutoring to know that nobody in human history ever learned math by only watching others do it.

Comment: the thig is I was going through SPivak's calculus, and this was a  problem, I thought I knew limits well enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit $L$ at $0$ means that for values of $x$ sufficiently close to $0$, $f(x)$ remains close to $L$.

But in the case of the inverse function $1/x$, you will always find values of $x$ close to $0$ that have their inverse far from $L$.

Take $x=1/(L+D)$, you can make it tiny, and at the same time far from $L$ as $1/x-L=D$.